# REST Many To Many Design

Tags: rest, api

Consider a web api exposing two kind of resources: Users and Teams with many-to-many relationship, typically a REST api will expose the following trivial endpoints to read data:

```
GET /users
GET /users/{id}
GET /users/{id}/teams
GET /teams
GET /teams/{id}
GET /teams/{id}/users
```

Now I am trying to design endpoints to manage relationships between the resources (endpoints to create/edit single resource through POST/PUT are trivial).
For a simple situation, we want to attach/remove a team (already existing) to a user (already existing). 
Are the following endpoints REST-compliant?

```
1- POST /users/{id}/teams (content= team ID) : to link a team to user 
2- PUT /users/{id}/teams/{id-team} (no content) : to link a team to user 
3- DELETE /users/{id}/teams/{id-team} (no content) : to remove team link
```

Is there any other Idea of endpoints which can be more convenient to use? (without using a distinct endpoint for relation management, like /relations)

Comment: Can you state more specifically what you mean by "convenient?"  Your second list of example URLs seems like they're as short as they can possibly be.

Comment: If you considered the link record as an entity in its own right, you could simply POST to `/userteamrelations`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey the second question is in the case for some reason one of my three proposals does not fit with REST conventions. And I cannot consider having a specific endpoint like your proposed /userteamrelations because I am not able to have a unique id for this kind of resource (because of legacy data structure), which means that I cannot have something like /userteamrelations/{id}

Comment: So your main concern is conforming to "REST conventions?"  I don't think you're going to get that anyway, since you don't have an ID available for these relations.

Answer (score 1):

REST doesn't care what spelling you use for your URIs, beyond the basics that they conform with [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A).  The machines don't care after that, in much the same way that the compiler doesn't care what variable names you use.  Follow any conventions you like.

If your URIs have a hierarchical structure, then you can take advantage of dot segments and [relative resolution](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2), which can be convenient.

However, you should be aware that the hierarchy implied by path segments in the URI does NOT actually imply a hierarchy of the resources.  `DELETE /A` says absolutely nothing about `/A/B` or `/A/B/C`; a successful delete will instruct the client to [invalidate](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) `/A` from its local cache, but `/A/B` will be left untouched.

That it turn means that if you are trying to request a change to the relationship, the target URI for the request should match the uri of the relationship.

In your case, you want a URI design that allows you to encode within it two pieces of information for the server.  Putting each of those pieces of information into a separate path segment is acceptable, and it may be easier to find routing implementations that support that schema, but you do have other choices available to you.

A common one would be to move the encoded information into the query part.

An uncommon one would both encoded values into the same path segment.  [Matrix parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048121/url-matrix-parameters-vs-request-parameters) is a useful search term.  RFC 3986 allows the use of `:` `&` `,` `;` `=` in path segments, so that gives you options like

```
/c58ad7cc-18ab-48d4-ae7b-070d9461f69d/id=7;id-team=4
/c58ad7cc-18ab-48d4-ae7b-070d9461f69d/id:7,id-team:4
```